# Javascript random background top right fixed

Tags: javascript, css, image, random, background

I got the code working, basically. I am having trouble getting the image set to be top right on the site layout. It's defaulting to bottom right and that's not what I desire.

Any help on getting it so the image displays at the top right since I'm at a loss.

I bet it's something simple too. >.o

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var bgColorArray = ['http://s33.postimg.org/5xlufyx6n/image.png','http://s33.postimg.org/y1sy7zkvz/BG2.png','http://s33.postimg.org/icmelisu7/BG3.png','http://s33.postimg.org/twvtrar9b/BG4.png','http://s33.postimg.org/xvy4urypr/BG5.png','http://s33.postimg.org/kpmh0h75r/BG6.png','http://s33.postimg.org/7d6aukl8f/BG7.png','http://s33.postimg.org/3xsf9m933/BG8.png','http://s33.postimg.org/4dhh7uz5r/BG9.png','http://s33.postimg.org/6kzi108lb/BG10.png','http://s33.postimg.org/3jmyfngjj/BG11.png','http://s33.postimg.org/55klqfkan/BG12.png'],
    selectBG = bgColorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgColorArray.length)];

document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + selectBG + ')';
</script>
```

As per requested here is the part of the CSS that's being effected:

Yeah sure, here's the CSS that's being effected:

```
html,body {
background:  url(http://s33.postimg.org/7nk1hqiwv/Woosh2.png) right bottom fixed no-repeat, url(http://s33.postimg.org/nk9mmywjj/ONEMORETIME.png) left top fixed no-repeat, url(http://s33.postimg.org/xgapmm2bj/Left_Side_Repeat.png) left bottom fixed repeat-y, url(http://s33.postimg.org/k00q0gawv/6_Done.png) fixed repeat;
color:#FFF;
text-shadow:#000 1px 1px 0;
font-family: "Comic Sans MS", "Trebuchet MS", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Verdana", sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
margin: 0;
padding:0;
height: 100%;
}
```

As for the HTML it's on a forum host, Zetaboards. So the HTML is mostly automated.

Comment: Can you post some html and css files? Your problem is not with the js code provided (I suppose your bg images render on screen).

Comment: You... actually just solved my problem by asking this question. It was placing it in the position of the top most layer of background images I have going on. You're a genius. ;)

Comment: check out this plunker created based on your code https://plnkr.co/edit/zEQbUhvDE4Ug2GYL96Tc?p=preview , hope it helps otherwise do the modification as er your code and let us know where you are facing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also set the default background position through Javascript, like this:

```
document.body.style.backgroundPosition = 'right top'
```

It should be quite self-explanatory.

And you can see that it works here.

```js
var bgColorArray = ['http://s33.postimg.org/5xlufyx6n/image.png', 'http://s33.postimg.org/y1sy7zkvz/BG2.png', 'http://s33.postimg.org/icmelisu7/BG3.png', 'http://s33.postimg.org/twvtrar9b/BG4.png', 'http://s33.postimg.org/xvy4urypr/BG5.png', 'http://s33.postimg.org/kpmh0h75r/BG6.png', 'http://s33.postimg.org/7d6aukl8f/BG7.png', 'http://s33.postimg.org/3xsf9m933/BG8.png', 'http://s33.postimg.org/4dhh7uz5r/BG9.png', 'http://s33.postimg.org/6kzi108lb/BG10.png', 'http://s33.postimg.org/3jmyfngjj/BG11.png', 'http://s33.postimg.org/55klqfkan/BG12.png'];
selectBG = bgColorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgColorArray.length)];

document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + selectBG + ')';
document.body.style.backgroundPosition = 'right top';
```

Comment: I tried that, but it was being overwritten by the CSS line it was plugging itself into. I now know what I was doing wrong and why this wasn't working when I tried. 

I thought I was crazy. I appreciate you confirming that I was, in fact, not.

Comment: Good to hear that it's working for you now. Unfortunately, I forgot to take a look at your CSS code, so I didn't take the overwriting into account. Yikes!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.bodyclass
{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: right;
    background-position: right 20px top 10px;
}
</style>
<body class="bodyclass">

<p id="demo">Click the button to change the text in this paragraph.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {

var bgColorArray = ['http://s33.postimg.org/5xlufyx6n/image.png','http://s33.postimg.org/y1sy7zkvz/BG2.png','http://s33.postimg.org/icmelisu7/BG3.png','http://s33.postimg.org/twvtrar9b/BG4.png','http://s33.postimg.org/xvy4urypr/BG5.png','http://s33.postimg.org/kpmh0h75r/BG6.png','http://s33.postimg.org/7d6aukl8f/BG7.png','http://s33.postimg.org/3xsf9m933/BG8.png','http://s33.postimg.org/4dhh7uz5r/BG9.png','http://s33.postimg.org/6kzi108lb/BG10.png','http://s33.postimg.org/3jmyfngjj/BG11.png','http://s33.postimg.org/55klqfkan/BG12.png'],
    selectBG = bgColorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgColorArray.length)];

document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + selectBG + ')';
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```